# getting previous version rather than latest version through CFBundleShortVersionString while app is updated in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, version

I am getting app version from given code

```
let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
```

I have updated app from app store and, when app get the app version from above code app return preview version instead of latest version.
why app app not give the latest version of app while app updated successfully from app store

- previous app version installed = 10.6.0
- and fetched version is 10.6.0
- now update app
- after updated
- current app version instaledl = 10.6.1
- and fetched version is 10.6.0

Comment: How you installed app first time, from AppStore?

Comment: previous app also installed through app store

Comment: can you try to reinstall and check again. it is some times takes time to update new version.

Comment: thanks, after deleting the app, it works fine but normal user don't know that it will be fixed after deleting and it is irritating process.

Answer (score 0):

This problem automatically solved. Means some time Appstore take extra time to reflect version in app while, build is already updated.

After one day app store show update option and when updated the app versioning problem became solved.
Thanks